# Gradle new publish plugin: repository hosting and how to specify username and password?

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

For hosting our own repository in http://example.com, which of the following softwares would you recommend for working with gradle?

```
Apache Archiva (open source)
CloudRepo (commercial)
Cloudsmith Package (commercial)
JFrog Artifactory Open Source (open source)
JFrog Artifactory Pro (commercial)
Sonatype Nexus OSS (open source)
Sonatype Nexus Pro (commercial)
```

Which software is Maven Central (https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central) using?

Gradle new maven publish plugin:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // change to point to your repo, e.g. http://my.org/repo
            url "http://example.com/maven/repository"
        }
    }
}
```

how to specify username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for adding credentials information is [documented here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository:credentials(org.gradle.api.Action)) and is simply:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "${url}"
        credentials {
            username = 'joe'
            password = 'secret'
        }
    }
}
```

I omitted the `publishing` part because the syntax is common to declaring dependency repositories *and* publishing ones.

As for the choice of repository manager, doing a feature comparison is beyond the scope of what I could / would answer. They all provide a different set of extra functionalities over serving files. Picking one will depend on your exact needs.